# How to render QWebEngineView to a printer?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, pdf, rendering

**My goal:** I would like to be able to store a HTML page taken from the qrc as a PDF file using qt 5.6.1.

**Limitations:**

- I can't use the *QWebEnginePage::print* nor *QWebEnginePage::printToPdf* methods since they have been added in versions 5.8 and 5.7 respectively
- Using *QTextDocument* instead is not an option, since I need a full HTML support, not just the limited subset the *QTextDocument* offers

**The problem:** The code below indeed shows the page on the screen, then the doc.pdf is created, which means that the page has been loaded without errors, but when I open the created PDF file a blank page is shown.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or missing?

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(this);

    setCentralWidget(view);

    QFile file(":/print.htm");
    QString str;

    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        str.append(file.readAll());
        view->setHtml(str);
        file.close();
    }

    connect(view, &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, this, &MainWindow::on_loadFinished);
}

void MainWindow::on_loadFinished(bool ok)
{
    if (ok)
    {
        QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);

        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
        printer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4));
        printer.setPageOrientation(QPageLayout::Portrait);
        printer.setColorMode(QPrinter::GrayScale);
        printer.setOutputFileName("doc.pdf");

        static_cast<QWebEngineView *>(sender())->render(&printer);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that updating is the only solution: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2016-April/021781.html or https://forum.qt.io/topic/53238/qwebengineview-print-method

Comment: True. I did that already and I use now the QWebEnginePage::printToPdf method. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it seems to me that updating is the only/best solution, because Qt 5.6 does not support printing a `QWebEngineView`:

References:

- [Qt mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2016-April/021781.html):

  > 1. How can I print a QWebEngineView content ?? with QWebView I only need to call the print method
  >
  > Printing with Chromium is surprisingly difficult to implement, but we
  >   aim to support printing to PDF in Qt 5.7:
- [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/53238/qwebengineview-print-method):

  > Looking at [this](https://trello.com/c/JE5kosmC/72-printing-support) and [this](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.5) it seems we wont have it in Qt 5.5 too.

**Alternative: using the old QtWebKit**

One can still use the `print` method from the deprecated `QWebView` class (which is replaced by `QWebEngineView`) if you build Qt from source (or use an older Qt version, for example Qt 5.5) as mentioned in the [Release Notes of Qt 5.6](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6):

> With Qt 5.6 the following modules are no longer part of the release
>   packages, but users can still build them from source:
>
> - Qt WebKit

*Note that I do not recommend this alternative, only use it if you are not able to update to the latest Qt version*